# not able to pip install eel . - Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, pip, eel

I'm trying to install eel library for python and I keep getting this message. I have tried upgrading pip but still no luck please help using windows 10, python 3.8 on visualstudio.

> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\program files
>   (x86)\python38-32\python.exe', '-m', 'pip',
>   '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w',
>   'C:\Users\inamu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpp16m1lcg', '--quiet',
>   'pycparser']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
>   full command output.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I'm guessing it has to do with gevent, which was the case for me. To solve it I did "pip install gevent==1.5a3"

If this doesn't fix it then I would try to troubleshoot which individual library is causing this issue then install a different release version using the library name then ==library update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following clean installation with dependancies as well.

```
pip install -I eel --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```